# JAVA: I'm trying to pass a string as a parameter in a new instance of a class but keep getting an error

Tags: java

I'm trying to pass a string when creating a new instance of my Palindrome class but it keeps throwing errors at me, Any help?

```
public class Palindrome {
    public String input;

    public void Palindrome(String stringinput){
        this.input = stringinput;
    }
}

public class PalindromeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Palindrome p = new Palindrome("test"); //i get an error here

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: The error would be "The constructor Palindrome(String) is undefined"

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to define a constructor, this

```
public void Palindrome(String stringinput){
```

should be

```
public Palindrome(String stringinput){
```

Otherwise it is considered a method with a return type of `void`.

Comment: @75inchpianist That isn't true. You can define methods with the same name as the class. (But you shouldn't.) That's why these errors happen.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I stand corrected. I never noticed that you could!

Answer (score 0):

The `void` keyword tells the compiler that this is a method signature, not a constructor.

```
public void Palindrome(String stringinput){
    this.input = stringinput;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Palindrome` class doesn't have an argumented constructor. It has only default non-arg constructor. I think you have mistaken to add `void` to `public void Palindrome(String stringinput){}` method. Because, you have made it as a method not as a constructor.